# ExcelLink: "Choose a Mathlink program to launch" after upgrading from 10.0.2 to 10.1

Tags: packages, interoperability, excel, excellink

After upgrading to 10.1, I now get a prompt "Choose a Mathlink program to launch" when I call code that uses ExcelLink.  This code worked prior to the update.  I am wondering if this is a configuration setting.  Is ExcelLink looking for Mathematica 10.0.2 (which is uninstalled during the 10.1 install).

Comment: This is a bug, which has been fixed in the development version. For 10.1.0, you may contact support@wolfram.com for a modified ExcelLink.m file, or use the patch from http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/472231

Answer (score 2):

Turning @ilian's comment into an answer:

> This is a bug, which has been fixed in the development version. For 10.1.0, you may contact support@wolfram.com for a modified ExcelLink.m file, or use the patch from http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/472231