# MathLink error msg: Libraries are not installed or outdated

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, excel, installation

I installed *Mathematica* 10.2.0.0, Excel 2013 32-bit, and MLink for Excel 3.6.0. In Excel, I added *Mathematica* Link in Add-Ins, and included the C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\ folder as a Trusted Location. OS is Win 7 64-bit.

When I click on the *Mathematica* Add-in icons, I get the error msg:

> "MathLink libraries are not installed or outdated. Before linking, you must install *Mathematica* or the latest version of MathLink libraries."

I have tried (1) reinstalling MLink for Excel 3.6.0, and (2) reinstalling *Mathematica* and Mlink, and (3) reinstalling Excel, *Mathematica* and MLink but the error msg still appears. I have also emailed Wolfram support but have received no acknowledgement after one week.

Inside *Mathematica*, ExcelLink works fine but inside Excel, Mlink isn't working.

Anyone else having this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen the response I posted to your question on Wolfram Community?  Did that help?

Comment: Specifically: at the end of [this thread](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/295101?p_p_auth=7yxakOq7).  Can't link to single posts for some reason.

Comment: Possibly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83165/12

Comment: Can you provide the link to your response on Wolfram Community please?

Comment: Check the link in my third comment first.  If that doesn't help, check the on in my second comment.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I added the path to the file you suggested and the error msg went away.